# Compactly generated space under quotient map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In May's Algebraic topology book, he states the following:

> Proposition: If $X$ is compactly generated and $\pi:X\to Y$ is a quotient map, then $Y$ is compactly generated $\iff$ $(\pi\times\pi)^{-1}(\Delta Y)$ is closed in $X\times X$.

Here's some notation that May uses: For topological spaces $Z$, $Z'$ We write $Z\times_c Z'$ as the product of $Z$ and $Z'$ with the usual topology, and $Z\times Z'$ as the $k$-ification of $Z\times_c Z'$.

Note that compactly generated (CG) means being weak Hausdorff (WH) and a $k$-space, $k$-space meaning all compactly closed sets are closed.

The $\Rightarrow$ implication is okay, Y being CG implies $\Delta Y$ is closed in $Y\times Y$, implying $(\pi\times\pi)^{-1}(\Delta Y)$ is closed in $X\times X$.

I'm partially done with the $\Leftarrow$ implication. I know how to prove that $Y$ is $k$-closed. Suppose that $A$ is a compactly closed set. It suffices to prove that $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is closed. Since $X$ is CG, it suffices to prove that $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is compactly closed. Let $g:K\to X$ be a map from a compact space $K$. Then $g^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(A))=(\pi\circ g)^{-1}(A)$, which is closed. Therefore, $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is compactly closed.

I'm having a hard time proving that $Y$ is WH in the $\Leftarrow$ implication. I would appreciate any hints!

Comment: `What is your definition of a compactly closed set?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My definition is as in May's book: A subspace $A$ of $X$ is compactly closed if $g^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $K$ for any map $g:K\to X$ from a compact space $K$ into $X$. I should also say that by "compact spaces," we mean both compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: $\Delta Y$ closed would mean that $Y$ is actually Hausdorff, and I don't think that need be the case. So I think there is a mistake in your $\Rightarrow$ proof.

Comment: As your proof for $Y$ being $k$-closed doesn't use that $(\pi\times \pi)^{-1}[\Delta Y]$ is closed at all (just that $X$ is $k$-closed and $\pi$ is quotient) it would seem reasonable to do use it here, to show that $Y$ is WH?

Comment: I think the proof of 2.14 in [these notes](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) can serve as inspiration. 2.20 finishes it then as when $Y$ is CG we know $\pi\times \pi$ is quotient.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that $\Delta Y$ is closed in $Y\times Y$, not $Y\times_c Y$, in my $\Rightarrow$ proof. I added the definitions for these two products to the original post. My $\Rightarrow$ proof, then, is a consequence of 2.14 in your linked notes.

Comment: May states a Lemma saying that if $X$ is a $k$-space (which you seem to call a $k$-closed space), then $X$ is weak Hausdorff if and only if $∆X$ is closed in $X × X$. Have you proved this? It does not seem be trivial.

Comment: By the way, I think that writing $X \times_c Y$ for the usual product and $X \times Y$ for the $k$-ification is really confusing. But that is caused by May.

Comment: I have not proved the weak Hausdorff condition equivalent to closed diagonal condition myself, but in the linked notes mentioned above, it is proposition 2.14. Also, I should've said $k$-space instead of $k$-closed.

Comment: Using the linked notes, does anything remain open? If not, you should close your question.

Comment: Nope, everything is answered. I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Charuvinda I suggest that you answer your own question. This will make it possible to clear it from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proposition 2.20 in the [linked notes](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) in the comments, we can prove that $\pi\times \pi$ is a quotient map. Thus, $\Delta Y=(\pi\times \pi)((\pi\times \pi)^{-1}\Delta Y)$ is a closed set in $Y\times Y$. This finishes proving that $Y$ is WH.